# Is there a way to add List<T> to redis in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, redis, stackexchange.redis

Is there a way to add `List<T>` to Redis in c# , but then when I retrieve the `List` from Redis , I should be able to do pagination and sorting?

I'm aware of the ability to store in sorted sets using a score for each row , but I have multiple columns that I need to sort for , so the whole process of inserting into Redis is repeated if I'm requesting to sort for a different column, which I want to avoid.

Comment: Are you looking for Serialization? Redis stores Key and Value (binary data).